# Apache Spark job reading from Cassandra table stalls on launch (spark-1.3.1)

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

We've been having intermittent issues with Spark 1.3.1 and the datastax Cassandra connector causing jobs to stall indefinitely when they are launched.

EDIT: I also tried the same approach with Spark 1.2.1 and the packaged 1.2.1 spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 and it resulted in the same symptoms.

We are using the following dependency:

```
var sparkCas = "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.10" % "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Our job code:

```
object ConnTransform {

  private val AppName = "ConnTransformCassandra"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val start = new DateTime(2015, 5, 27, 1, 0, 0)

    val master = if (args.length >= 1) args(0) else "local[*]"

    // Create the spark context.
    val sc = {
      val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName(AppName)
        .setMaster(master)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.10.101.202,10.10.102.139,10.10.103.74")

      new SparkContext(conf)
    }

    sc.cassandraTable("alpha_dev", "conn")
      .select("data")
      .where("timep = ?", start)
      .where("sensorid IN ?", Utils.sensors)
      .map(Utils.deserializeRow)
      .saveAsTextFile("output/raw_data")
  }
}
```

As you can see, the code is pretty simple (and it was more complex, but we've been attempting to narrow down the root cause of this issue).

Now, this job worked earlier today - data was successfully put into the directory specified.  However, now when it is run we see the job start, get to the point just before it starts processing blocks, and sit there indefinitely.

Output from the job below shows the log messages seen so far, and at the time of writing the job has been stalled for almost an hour.  If we set the logging level to DEBUG the only thing you see after that point in the job are heartbeat pings between akka workers.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-10-102-53:~/projects/icespark$ /home/ubuntu/spark/spark-1.3.1/bin/spark-submit --class com.splee.spark.ConnTransform splee-analytics-assembly-0.1.0.jar
15/05/27 21:15:21 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.1
15/05/27 21:15:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
15/05/27 21:15:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
15/05/27 21:15:21 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(ubuntu); users with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu)
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-10-10-102-53.us-west-2.compute.internal:51977]
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 51977.
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-2466ff66-bb50-4d52-9d34-1801d69889b9/blockmgr-60e75214-1ba6-410c-a564-361263636e5c
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-72f1e849-c298-49ee-936c-e94c462f3df2/httpd-f81c2326-e5f1-4f33-9557-074f2789c4ee
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55357
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 55357.
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://ip-10-10-102-53.us-west-2.compute.internal:4040
15/05/27 21:15:22 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ubuntu/projects/icespark/splee-analytics-assembly-0.1.0.jar at http://10.10.102.53:55357/jars/splee-analytics-assembly-0.1.0.jar with timestamp 1432761322942
15/05/27 21:15:23 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID <driver> on host localhost
15/05/27 21:15:23 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-10-10-102-53.us-west-2.compute.internal:51977/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/05/27 21:15:23 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 58479
15/05/27 21:15:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/05/27 21:15:23 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:58479 with 265.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 58479)
15/05/27 21:15:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.101.28:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.101.28 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.103.60:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.103.60 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.102.154:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.102.154 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.101.145:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.101.145 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.103.78:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.103.78 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.102.200:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.102.200 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.102.73:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.102.73 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.103.205:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.103.205 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.101.205:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.10.101.205 (us-west-2)
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.103.74:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.101.202:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.10.102.139:9042 added
15/05/27 21:15:24 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Splee Dev
15/05/27 21:15:25 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Splee Dev
```

If anyone has any ideas what could be causing this job (which previously produced results) to stall in this way and can shed some light on the situation it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try the milestone release rather than relying on snapshots

Comment: You may also want to try assigning spark.driver.host, the hostname that is getting passed may not be resolved correctly
ip-10-10-102-53.us-west-2.compute.internal

Comment: @RussS We downgraded to 1.2.1 with the spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 at 1.2.1 with the same results.